# How does Perl decide to treat a scalar as a string or a number?

Tags: perl, string, numbers, scalar

Consider the following code and its output:

#### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my $HOURS_PER_DAY = 24.0 * 1.0;
my $BSA = 1.7 * 1.0;
my $MCG_PER_MG = 1000.0 * 1.0;
my $HOURS_DURATION    = 20.0 * $HOURS_PER_DAY;
my $dummy = $HOURS_PER_DAY * $BSA * $MCG_PER_MG * $HOURS_DURATION;
print Dumper($HOURS_PER_DAY);
print Dumper( $BSA);
print Dumper( $MCG_PER_MG);
print Dumper( $HOURS_DURATION );
```

#### Output

```
$VAR1 = 24;
$VAR1 = '1.7';
$VAR1 = 1000;
$VAR1 = 480;
```

---

As you can see, the second variable is treated as strings, while the first and the forth ones are treated as numbers. Anybody has any idea what is the underlying logic?

**Edit** arithmetic calculations that were added do not completely solve the problem (see the $BSA variable).

---

```
$ perl -v

This is perl, v5.10.0 built for cygwin-thread-multi-64int
(with 6 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2007, Larry Wall
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Data::Dumper's job is to serialize data and you can't tell much about what perl is doing internally with the data based on its output. The [Devel::Peek](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Peek) module can dump the underlying flags and values stored in the variables. The Devel::Peek POD explains the significance of the flags.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Devel::Peek;

my $HOURS_PER_DAY = 24.0 * 1.0;
my $BSA = 1.7 * 1.0;
my $MCG_PER_MG = 1000.0 * 1.0;
my $HOURS_DURATION    = 20.0 * $HOURS_PER_DAY;
my $dummy = $HOURS_PER_DAY * $BSA * $MCG_PER_MG * $HOURS_DURATION;

Dump($HOURS_PER_DAY);
Dump($BSA);
Dump($MCG_PER_MG);
Dump($HOURS_DURATION);

__END__
SV = PVNV(0xd71ff0) at 0xd87f90
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADBUSY,PADMY,IOK,NOK,pIOK,pNOK)
  IV = 24
  NV = 24
  PV = 0
SV = PVNV(0xd71fc8) at 0xd87f60
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADBUSY,PADMY,NOK,pIOK,pNOK)
  IV = 1
  NV = 1.7
  PV = 0
SV = PVNV(0xd72040) at 0xd87f40
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADBUSY,PADMY,IOK,NOK,pIOK,pNOK)
  IV = 1000
  NV = 1000
  PV = 0
SV = IV(0xd8b408) at 0xd87f30
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADBUSY,PADMY,IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 480
# compare the above output to output without the assignment to $dummy:
SV = IV(0x7b0eb8) at 0x7adf90
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADBUSY,PADMY,IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 24
SV = NV(0x7c7c90) at 0x7adf60
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADBUSY,PADMY,NOK,pNOK)
  NV = 1.7
SV = IV(0x7b13d8) at 0x7adf40
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADBUSY,PADMY,IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 1000
SV = IV(0x7b1408) at 0x7adf30
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADBUSY,PADMY,IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 480
```

Answer (score 6):

Your whole concept of Perl treating variables as strings or numbers is flawed. Perl will treat your variables the right way when you need it to, for example, arithmetic operators **always** take treat their argument as numbers (assuming you aren't abusing operator overloading or some such).

You shouldn't worry about this: Perl knows what it's doing.

Answer (score 5):

Data::Dumper is using a simple pattern on the string representation of the variable to determine if it is a number.  From the source code:

```
...
elsif ($val =~ /^(?:0|-?[1-9]\d{0,8})\z/) { # safe decimal number
  $out .= $val;
}
else {               # string
...
```

This doesn't match numbers that have a decimal point which explains the behavior you observed.

Comment: Perl does NOT remember the last use of a variable. It does remember when a variable is both a valid integer, float or string when either of those is used. *However this does not affect the semantics of the variable* (except in two cases, bitwise operators and syscall).

Answer (score 0):

Quick dirty way to force a numeric context:

```
print Dumper( $HOURS_DURATION + 0.0 );
```

If your concern is how the data will be displayed then the clean way is:-

```
printf "%5.2d",$HOURS_DURATION;
```